# OpenLayers, Bing, continuous map layer

Tags: javascript, openlayers, bing-maps

I'm trying to get the Bing layer continuous in OpenLayers, but I cannot find any solution.
As we can see on example (http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/bing.html), when we scroll the map horizontally or vertically, layer is not continuous as the Google map is (http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/google.html). It's quite weird when we zoom out and the map doesn't fit into viewport leaving blank white background on the left and right side.
Any ideas?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This example shows how to achieve horizontal repeat:

- http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/wrapDateLine.html

Not sure how to solve the white background when zoomed out, I do not think Openlayers supports this.